# Display some text by manage the onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to hide and show my section (Question1, Question2,...) and manage the onclick. So, by clicking Question1 will be dispalied SomeText and by clicking Question2 will be dispalied other text..and so on...How can I do that?
I also would like to have a left section with all the Question and a right section which display the answear.

**Code:**

```
<strong font="" size="5" face="arial" color="black"><b>Question1</b></strong>
<div class="section" style="padding-top: 0.5cm" size="2" face="arial" color="black">
    <p>
        Some text
        <br/><br />
    </p>
</div>

<strong font="" size="5" face="arial" color="black"><b><br />Question</b></strong>
<div class="section" style="padding-top: 0.5cm" size="2" face="arial" color="black">
    <p>
        Some text
    </p>
</div>

<style>
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    div.section {
        text-align: justify;
    }
    /*]]>*/
</style>
```

Comment: Multiple ways in pure CSS. `:target`, `<input type="checkbox">` etc.

Comment: This forum has loads of questions about accordions (using CSS, javascript/jquery)

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to do this, You can do it with checkbox and label or you can do it with javascript.
But one piece of advice i would like to give is You should do a thorough research before posting a question.
The most Basic and simple way to do this is via jQuery.

```js
jQuery('.question').on("click",function(){
    jQuery('.section').hide();
    var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    jQuery('#section'+id).show();
  });
```

```css
.section{
  display:none;
}
.question{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" class="question"><b>Question1</b></div>
 <div id="section1" class="section">
 Some text 1<br>
   <br>
   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
</div>
<div id="2" class="question"><b>Question2</b></div>
<div id="section2" class="section">
   Some text 1<br>
   <br>
   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
Some text 2
</div>
```